# type issues writing a java "flatten" method

Tags: java, generics

I tried to come up with a nice scala-like flatten method for Java, but get lost in the types:

```
public static <T, IC extends Collection<T>, OC extends Collection<IC>> IC flatten(OC values) {
  IC result = (IC) new HashSet<T>();
  for (Collection<T> value : values) {
    result.addAll(value);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This worked in 1.6 (with warning), but in 1.7 I get:

```
    error: invalid inferred types for T,IC; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: Set<AffiliationRole>
    bound(s): Collection<Object>
    where T,IC,OC are type-variables:
    T extends Object declared in method <T,IC,OC>flatten(OC)
    IC extends Collection<T> declared in method <T,IC,OC>flatten(OC)
    OC extends Collection<IC> declared in method <T,IC,OC>flatten(OC)
```

*Update*:

Actual code that produces the compile error in 1.7:

```
    HashSet<Collection<String>> lists = new HashSet<Collection<String>>();
    Collection<String> flatten = ArrayUtil.flatten(lists);
```

Can be sort of fixed with:
        Collection flatten = ArrayUtil., HashSet>>flatten(lists);

Although a (much) better solution in the comments from assylias:

```
    public static <T> Collection<T> flatten(Collection<? extends Collection<T>> values) {
      Collection<T> result = new HashSet<T>();
      for (Collection<T> value : values) {
        result.addAll(value);
      }
      return result;
    }
```

Comment: It compiles fine for me in java 1.7

Comment: Same here, no problem (but a warning)...

Comment: Please include the full `-version` string of the Java 7 compiler that's rejecting this.

Comment: Any reason why you don't change the signature to `public static <T, OC extends Collection<Collection<T>>> Collection<T> flatten(OC values)` and get rid of the cast? Or even (more readable IMO): `public static <T> Collection<T> flatten(Collection<? extends Collection<T>> values)`

Comment: Agreed. Do not declare `IC` because then the caller decides what type it is, and it may not be `HashSet`. Pay attention to unchecked cast warnings - they exist for a reason.

Comment: the method itself is fine. you forgot to post the line that triggers the compile error.

Comment: good point, I've added it and the solution from the comments. Thanks for comments and solution.